# Why does the AddReservoirConstraintWithActive return MODEL INVALID?

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

In my model CP_SAT, I need to check that each time my raw material stock is sufficient to produce.
So I use AddReservoirConstraintWithActive:

```
model.AddReservoirConstraintWithActive(listtime, listdemand, listactive, volmax_negat, volstock)
```

Each list contains 190 values.
For `listactive` type values are only `model.NewBoolVar`

But for `listtime` and `listdemand`, type values are a mix of real values and `model.NewIntVar` :

[image: listtime overview]

And the interval values `volmax_negat` `volstock` are real values :

[image: volmax_negat and volstock overview]

Why OR-toold can't solve the model and send me back this error :
`Invalid model: expression must be constant: vars: 123 coeffs: 1`

[image: error message]

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only constant demands is supported, as stated in the message.

And in the [code](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/5425dedcfbb22cb74c636c1374a9b5ad684b1eb5/ortools/sat/python/cp_model.py#L1392) and in the [doc](https://or-tools.github.io/docs/python/ortools/sat/python/cp_model.html#CpModel.AddReservoirConstraintWithActive).

Comment: Ok, Thank you Laurent, Would there be an alternative to manage variable demand?